# This buying function in the tutorial never pays the contract, does it?

Tags: solidity, ether

It doesn't look like the contract is ever paid here. Is this a miscode or am I reading it incorrectly? Where does the exchange of ether occur?

```
function buy() payable returns (uint amount){
    amount = msg.value / buyPrice;            // calculates the amount of token
    if (balanceOf[this] < amount) throw;      // checks if it has enough token to sell
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;          // adds the amount of token to buyer's balance
    balanceOf[this] -= amount;                // subtracts the amount of token from seller's balance
    Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);       // execute an event reflecting the change
    return amount;                            // ends function and returns
}
```

Comment: would you please share the tuto

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, and you have not provided any context to the submitted code snippet.

Comment: Apologies, it can be found here: https://ethereum.org/token

Answer (score 3):

this buy function transfers to the buyer an amount of tokens against the received ethers.
It gets payed because this function is `payable` so it receives ethers via msg.value and allocate to the buyer an equivalent amount of these tokens in `balanceof[]`.

Comment: So payable automatically means that someone has transferred ether, which is recorded as msg.value? Does not need to be programmed?

Comment: it means that user can send ethers when calling this function. a contract is an account so it receives fund as the normal account does

Comment: but where in the code is the exchange of ether written?